# How to monitor system performance over time

Tags: bash, performance, monitoring

I wrote the below script to determine how my system is holding up against various games. It checks all the vitals (GPU, RAM, and CPU) and then appends the data to a log file. Is this a reasonable approach or is there an easier, more efficient way to do this? Any suggestions to improve the script?

```
load=$(aticonfig --odgc | grep 'GPU load')
temp=$(aticonfig --odgt | grep Sensor)
date=$(date)
free=$(free -h)
cpus=$(top -bn 1 | grep Cpu)
printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n\n%s\n%s\n\n' "$date" "$load" "$temp" "$free" "$cpus" >> performance_log
```

I use `watch -n60` command to execute the script.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure which distro you're using, but can you get any of this from historical `sar` records?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data for long term evaluation, you could use munin to graph it. I haven't seen plugins for GPUs, but since you figured out how to get the data, it isn't a big deal to write a munin plugin: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins